# Display next 3 posts based on custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am wondering if anyone could help me accomplish something like this: https://medium.com/thoughts-and-words/5ccef7b3e1fc with custom post types?

I have a custom post type called projects and custom taxonomy called project-category.  I would like to show the next 3 projects in the same project-category on the single project page.  One will show title and excerpt and the other two will just show titles.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather all you need to do is query the 3 posts and step though each one using **[the_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)**. I have not used it like this so not 100% that is how it works.

> **the_post()** Retrieves the next post, sets up the post, sets the 'in the loop' property to true.

```
$project_query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type'      => 'projects',
    'taxonomy'       => 'project-category'
    );

query_posts ( $project_query ); while ( have_posts() ) :  

//Post 1
the_post();
the_title();
the_content();

//Post 2
the_post();
the_title();

//Post 3
the_post();
the_title();

endwhile;
```

Comment: Bash, thanks for the response! This is almost what I need.  The only problem is that this pulls the next 3 posts in any project-category.  I need to pull the next 3 post in the current project category.  For example, if the current post is in the web-design and identity project-category, I only want to show 3 more posts from web-design/identity. How can I modify your code to use the taxonomy term?

Comment: looks like you found a good logical answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bash for getting me started, I've come up with a decent solution that's working well so far.

Here's the code...

```
// create array of current taxonomy term slugs
$current_project_term_slugs = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'project_type', array('fields' => 'slugs'));
// convert array to comma seperated values in string to query posts with same taxonomy terms
$term_slugs = join(', ', $current_project_term_slugs);
// set up query args
$project_query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type'      => 'projects',
    'project_type'       => $term_slugs,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
    );

query_posts ( $project_query ); while ( have_posts() ) :  

// next project primary
the_post();
the_title();
the_excerpt();

// next project secondary 1
the_post();
the_title();

// next project secondary 2
the_post();
the_title();

endwhile;
```